# Trouble pasting into Cygwin 4;2~

Tags: cygwin

When I try to paste into Cygwin using Shift+Ins (whether from inside or outside Cygwin) it turns into "4;2~". I'm running Windows 10. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off FnLock. I had FnLock on so the sequence was being interpreted as Shift+F12.